# Is it possible to start nodemon and browser-sync with one npm script in an Express app?

Tags: javascript, express, browser-sync, nodemon, npm-scripts

In my Express app I use `nodemon` and `browser-sync` together. I have those npm scripts in my `package.json` :

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node  ./bin/www",
    "start:nodemon": "nodemon ./bin/www",
    "start:debug": "SET DEBUG=img:* & npm run start:nodemon",
    "start:browser-sync": " browser-sync start --proxy 'localhost:3000' --files 'public,views'",
    "test": "npm run start:debug & npm run start:browser-sync"
  }
```

Currently, I open two `cmd` windows and in the first one I run `start:debug`, and in the other one I run `start:browser-sync` . Everything works just fine.

I thought I could combine those scripts and run them as it is done in my `test` script, however, it doesn't work that way. It looks like it starts `nodemon` and ignores `browser-sync`.  So, can I start those two scripts somehow together with one npm script, or it is technically impossible and I have to run two `cmds` for it to work?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `&` between commands means "execute the first command in background, while the second one in foreground" in Bash, while in Windows cmd this means "execute the second command after the first one completed".

To run commands in parallel in platform-independent way you can use e.g. [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all):

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node  ./bin/www",
    "start:nodemon": "nodemon ./bin/www",
    "start:debug": "SET DEBUG=img:* & npm run start:nodemon",
    "start:browser-sync": " browser-sync start --proxy 'localhost:3000' --files 'public,views'",
    "test": "run-p start:debug start:browser-sync"
  }
}
```

Or you can give a try to [run-z](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-z):

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node  ./bin/www",
    "start:nodemon": "nodemon ./bin/www",
    "start:debug": "SET DEBUG=img:* & npm run start:nodemon",
    "start:browser-sync": " browser-sync start --proxy 'localhost:3000' --files 'public,views'",
    "test": "run-z start:debug,start:browser-sync"
  }
}
```

The latter can be used without installation. Just run

```sh
npx run-z start:debug,start:browser-sync
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the first one and got an error `[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`

Comment: That seems like your application issue.  Try to start it directly to see the reson of application crash.